# what is the solution to this equation

Tags: graphing-functions, conic-sections

I already did this on paper. I want to know if I got it correct.
what do you think is the answer to this quadratic (parabola) equation?

$-x^2-2x+1 =0 $

Comment: What answer? What are you trying to solve?

Comment: Perhaps you are asking for the values of $x $ such that $-x^2-2x+1=\color{red}{0}$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Could you please include your work on the problem so we can see if it's correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to find the ***roots*** of the parabola ($-x^2-2x+1=0$)

Try:

- Eliminating the negative of the leading coefficient by multiplying by $-1$
- Try factoring (isn't going to work in this case)
- Use the quadratic formula: $$x=\dfrac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a},$$
  where $a$, $b$, $c$ are the coefficients in the equation $ax^2+bx+c=0$
- Try finding the $a$, $b$, $c$ values of $x^2+2x-1=0$

In the end, your solution(s) should be:

> $$x=-1\pm\sqrt{2}$$